# C printf prints an array that I didn't ask for

Tags: arrays, c, char, printf, c-strings

I have recently started learning C and I got into this problem where printf() prints an array I didn't ask for.
I was expecting an error since I used %s format in char array without the '\0', but below is what I got.

```
char testArray1[] = { 'a','b','c'};
char testArray2[] = { 'q','w','e','r','\0' };

printf("%c", testArray1[0]);
printf("%c", testArray1[1]);
printf("%c\n", testArray1[2]);

printf("%s\n", testArray1);
```

the result is

```
abc
abcqwer
```

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "an error"? Do you mean you expected the code not to compile?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes that's what I meant :)

Comment: @aufe: That's a data problem, not a syntax or type error, and that sort of thing can't be caught at compile time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%s` indeed stop when encountered `\0`, but `testArray1` didn't have that `\0`, so it keeps printing the following bytes in the memory.

And the compiler magically(actually intentionally) places the `testArray2` next to `testArray1`, the memory is like:

```
a b c q w e r \0
^                testArray1 starts here
      ^          testArray2 starts here
```

And the `%s` will print all of those chars above until it meets a `\0`.

You can validate that by:

```c
printf("%d\n", testArray2 == testArray1 + 3);
// prints `1`(true)
```

---

As your question, there was no error because the `a ... r \0` sequece in memory is owned by your process. Only the program is trying to access an address not owned by it, the OS will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

The format `"%s"` expects that the corresponding argument points to a string: sequence of characters terminated by the zero character `'\0'`.

```
printf("%s\n", testArray1);
```

As the array `testArray1` does not contain a string then the call above has undefined behavior.

Instead you could write

```
printf("%.*s\n", 3,testArray1);
```

or

```
printf("%.3s\n", testArray1);
```

specifying exactly how many elements of the array you are going to output.

Pay attention to that in C instead of these declarations

```
char testArray1[] = { 'a','b','c'};
char testArray2[] = { 'q','w','e','r','\0' };
```

you may write

```
char testArray1[3] = { "abc" };
char testArray2[] = { "qwer" };
```

or that is the same

```
char testArray1[3] = "abc";
char testArray2[] = "qwer";
```

In C++ the first declaration will be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Add zero at the end of first array:

```
char testArray1[] = { 'a','b','c', 0 };
```

Otherwise `printf` continues with memory after `'c'` until zero byte and there is the second array.

PS: zero `0` is 100% identical to longer ASCII `'\0'`.